# Map Function Javascript - How to store 2 values when we select something in dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have data in the form of JSON as given below:

```
[
    {
        "course_name": "React",
        "course_id": 2
    },
    {
        "course_name": "Python",
        "course_id": 1
    }
]
```

Below is the code I have written in React. According to this whenever there is a change in the dropdown, the id is stored in the value.

```
       <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
            onChange={handleChange}
            label="CourseList"
          >
            {
              dropdown.map(options => 
                <MenuItem value={options["course_id"]} >{options["course_name"]}</MenuItem>
              )
            }
          </Select>



  const handleChange = (event) => {
    handleChangecourse_id(event.target.value);
    setVal(event.target.value);
  }
```

Basically, I want both the values(whatever gets selected, it's course_id and course_name) and set it to two different states.
What I thought roughly if(val === dropdown.map(options=> options["course_id"]), then store the course_name somewhere, but I am unable to proceed.
Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below method after getting the selected id to get complete object.

```
let course = dropdown.filter(val => val.course_id==event.target.value);
```